# Making DiveIntoPython3 work in IE8 (fixing a Javascript performance issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to fix the performance problem with Dive Into Python 3 on IE8. Visit [this page](http://diveintopython3.org/native-datatypes.html) in IE8 and, after a few moments, you will see the following popup:

[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/87045/permalinks/dip3-ie8-perf.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/87045/permalinks/dip3-ie8-perf.png)

I traced down the culprit down to this line in `j/dip3.js`

... find("tr:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ") td:nth-child(2)");

If I disable it (and return from the function immediately), the "Stop executing this script?" dialog does not appear as the page now loads fairly fast.

I am no Javascript/jquery expert, so I ask you fellow developers as to why this query is making IE slow. Is there a fix for it?

**Edit**: you can download the [entire webpage](http://www.diveintopython3.org/d/diveintopython3-html-latest.zip) (980K) for local viewing/editing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to need a bit of rewriting.

nth-child is a slow operation. You should implement the current functionality by generating classes or ids that would be common for the TDs in table and elements from the refs collection (dip3.js line 183). and then:

```
refs.each(function(i) {
  var a = $(this);
  var li = a.parents("pre").next("table").find("td."+a.attr('class'));
  li.add(a).hover(function() { a.css(hip); li.css(hip); },
  function() { a.css(unhip); li.css(unhip); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This popup message is misleading - it doesn't actually mean that IE is running slowly, but that the number of executed script statements has exceeded a certain threshold.  Even if the script executes very quickly, you'll still see this message if you go over the limit.  The only way to get rid of it is to reduce the number of statements executed or edit the registry.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

I find Microsoft's implementation of this very annoying.  It makes assumptions about the speed of your computer.